# Isolatedness of Lefschetz map - almost there

Tags: general-topology

$f$ is a Lefschetz map on a compact manifold X. And I need to show the Lefschetz fixed point is isolated.

I proved that the graph of f is transversal to the diagonal inside $X \times X$, then I don't know how to proceed from here. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Please give *much* more information. The more you explain about your problem, the easier it will be for people to help - so give as much information as possible! What is $f$? What is $V$? What, *exactly*, is it that you are trying to prove about them?

Comment: @ZevChonoles Thanks - I am adding *much more* information...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose $x_0$ is a Lefschetz fixed point. Take a chart $(U,\phi)$ around $x_0.$ Then in this coordinate neighborhood (after composing with proper coordinate functions) I can think of $f$ as a map from open ball in $\mathbb{R}^n,\,\,$ (say $B$) to itself with $f(0)=0.$ Now consider we have a function $f:B\rightarrow B$  such that $f(0)=0.$ Consider the function $g=f-id.$ Then $g(0)=0$ and by lefschetz condition $det(dg)(0)\neq 0$ (as 1 is not an eigenvalue of $df$). Hence $g$ is a local diffeomorphism by inverse function theorem and we are done.
Just out of curiosity are you reading the book differential topology by Guillemin and Pollack.

Comment: Yes I am reading the book differential topology by Guillemin and Pollack.

Comment: Hi, given 1 is not an eigenvalue of $df$, why we get det$(f-id) \neq 0$? I thought it should be det$(df-id) \neq 0$?

Comment: @MathSnail Sorry for the typo. It should be $det(df-id).$

Comment: Hi @tessellation, thank you for the clarification. But I could follow you at the very last step - why we are done after showing $g$ is a local diffeomorphism? Thank you!

Comment: If g is a diffeo then g is bijective in that small nbd. If f has another fixed point a in that nbd then g(a)=0. This will contradict the bijcetivity of g.

Comment: Thank you so much @tessellation!

Answer (score 5):

An alternative solution, directly continuing Jellyfish's beginning of a solution to G&P's Problem 5-10, Chapter 1.

Since $df_x$ has no eigenvalues equal $1$, by Problem 5-9 of G&P

$$\text{graph}(df_x) \pitchfork \Delta(T_x(X)\times T_x(X)).$$

It's an easy exercise to check that $\Delta(T_x(X)\times T_x(X)) = T_{x,x}(\Delta(X\times X)),$ so we now have 
$$\text{graph}(f) \pitchfork \Delta(X\times X).$$
 The overlap of these two sets is $W := \{(x,f(x))\colon x\in X, x=f(x)\},$ in bijective (in fact, diffeomorphic) correspondence with the set of fixed points of $f$. Now, by the transversality theorem from G&P, $W$ is a submanifold of $X\times X$. Furthermore, $\text{codim}(W) = \text{codim}(\text{graph}(f)) + \text{codim}(\Delta(X\times X)) = 2n.$ But this shows that $W$ is in fact a manifold of zero dimension, that is a set of isolated points. Thus the set of fixed points of $f$ is also an isolated set. As a subset of compact $X$ it must thus be finite.

Comment: how did you say that  we now have
graph(f)⋔Δ(X×X) ? Is it general theorem ?